# How do I get the visitor's current timezone then convert timezone.now() to string of the local time in Django 1.4?

Tags: python, django, timezone

I understand that the best practice now with Django 1.4 is to store all `datetime` in UTC and I agree with that. I also understand that all timezone conversation should be done in the template level like this:

```
{% load tz %}

{% timezone "Europe/Paris" %}
    Paris time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

However, I need to convert the UTC time to the `request`'s local time all in Python. I can't use the template tags since I am returning the string in JSON using Ajax (more specifically [Dajaxice](http://www.dajaxproject.com/)).

Currently this is my code `ajax.py`:

```
# checked is from the checkbox's this.value (Javascript).
datetime = timezone.now() if checked else None

$ order_pk is sent to the Ajax function.
order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_pk)
order.time = datetime
order.save()

return simplejson.dumps({
    'error': False,
    'datetime': dateformat.format(datetime, 'F j, Y, P') if checked else 'None'
})
```

So even if the current time is `April 14, 2012, 5:52 p.m.` in EST time (my local timezone), the JSON response will return `April 14, 2012, 9:52 p.m`, because that is the UTC time.

Also I noticed that Django stores a template variable called `TIME_ZONE` for each request (not actually part of the `request` variable), so since my is `America/New_York`, I'm assuming that Django can figure out each visitor's own local timezone (based on HTTP header)?

Anyway, so my question is two-fold:

1. How do I get the visitor's local timezone in my `ajax.py`? (Probably pass it as a string argument like `{{ TIME_ZONE }}`)
2. With the visitor's local timezone, how to convert the UTC `timezone.now()` to the local timezone and output as a string using Django's `dateformat`?

**EDIT:** for @agf

`timezone.now()` gives the UTC time when `USE_TZ = True`:

```
# From django.utils.timezone
def now():
    """
    Returns an aware or naive datetime.datetime, depending on settings.USE_TZ.
    """
    if settings.USE_TZ:
        # timeit shows that datetime.now(tz=utc) is 24% slower
        return datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    else:
        return datetime.now()
```

Is there anyway to convert a `datetime` to something other than UTC? For example, can I do something like `current_time = timezone.now()`, then `current_time.replace(tzinfo=est)` (EST = Eastern Standard Time)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to read the [Django Timezones docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/i18n/timezones/) carefully.

One important point:

> there's no equivalent of the Accept-Language HTTP header that Django could use to determine the user's time zone automatically.

You have to ask the user what their timezone is or just use a default.

You also need to make sure:

```
USE_TZ = True
```

in your `settings.py`.

Once you have a timezone `tz`, you can:

```
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.activate(tz)

datetime = timezone.now() if checked else None
```

to get a timezone-aware `datetime` object in timezone `tz`.

Comment: Well I'll first have to do `timezone.now()` before `timezone.activate(tz)` and store that to `order` first right? But then there will be 2 different `datetime`.

Comment: @hobbes3 if you want a timezone-aware datetime for the default timezone, then yes. If you want a timezone-aware UTC datetime, and the default timezone isn't UTC,  then use you need to convert to UTC.

Comment: @hobbes3 You can  always use `somedatetime.replace(tz=sometz)`.

Comment: Ya, sorry I just realized my first comment is very ambiguous. I meant to say that I want to first capture the currnent UTC time with `current_time = timezone.now()`, attach that to `order` (store it to the database), then use the same `current_time`, convert it to ETC or whatever timezone the visitor uses, then convert that to a string, and finally pass it back to JavaScript via Ajax. I hope that made sense.

Comment: @hobbes3 If you want the current UTC time, use `datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tz=utc)` for that (right from the docs I linked), and `timezone.now()` for the current local time.

Comment: Actually I already have `USE_TZ = True` and `TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'` and `timezone.now()` gives the UTC time.

Comment: @hobbes3 You still have to `timezone.activate(tz)` as I showed in my post. `timezone.now()` gives a timezone-aware `datetime`, even in UTC, but that doesn't mean it always uses the local time.

Comment: Oh so you're saying, use `timezone.activate(tz)`, then do `timezone.now()` to get the *local* time, then convert that to UTC and store that in the database?

Comment: @hobbes3 I was assuming that since what you're sending through JSON is for display only, it doesn't have to match the time stored in the database down to the microsecond, so it's perfectly safe to use two different `datetime` objects so you don't have to convert back-and-forth between UTC and the local timezone at all. However, you can always use `replace(tz=thetz)` in either direction, but the purpose of `timezone.now()` as a convenience function is to be able to give you a timezone aware local time easily.

Answer (score 6):

While the browser does not send any headers to the server that would indicate a timezone, the JavaScript environment *does* know its current timezone.

This has two important effects: While the server can't find out your current timezone on the initial request, you *can* send down some javascript code which will determine the TZ offset and send that information back to the server so that the zone info can be associated with the current session from that point forward.

But more importantly, if you're sending your time value inside JSON data which will be interpreted by the browser client-side, the browser's timezone doesn't *need* to be known. Instead, you only have to ensure the timezone offset is present in your JSON output so that the browser can do its own timezone math after-the-fact.

```
var now = new Date()
var offset_minutes = now.getTimezoneOffset()  # e.g. 240 for GMT-0400
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the users' timezones, it makes sense to me that this should be done on the browser with Javascript.

I pass something like this into the template:

```
{"t": str(obj.timestamp))
```

Where obj is an instance of a django model where the timestamp field is of type DateTimeField.

The template:

```
<div class="timestring">{{ t }}</div> 
...
<script>
  $('.timestring').each(function(){
    var d = new Date($(this).text());
    $(this).text(d.toLocaleDateString() + ", " + d.toLocaleFormat("%r (%Z)"));
  })
</script>
```

For me, this outputs something like: 2/15/2017, 05:22:24 PM (PST)

The relevant documentation:

- [Javascript Date class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm) (see especially the constructor which accepts datestrings, and the toLocaleFormat() method)
- [strftime (comes with lots of date formatting shortcuts)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)