# Django timezone localization

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a web site that you can send a post just like fb
I want to know how could I handle the post time for each local time?
I was thinking about changing timezone.now to utc and save it. But when I want show it to user 
how convert it too user's local time?
And what is professional's solution?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the visitor's current timezone then convert timezone.now() to string of the local time in Django 1.4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157720/how-do-i-get-the-visitors-current-timezone-then-convert-timezone-now-to-strin)

Answer (score 1):

Django supports working with time zones out of the box ([documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/)). Setting `USE_TZ=True` enables time zone support: django will store timezone-aware datetimes in the database; when it comes to template rendering - it'll show datetimes for the user's time zone.